# send html using mailx

Tags: bash, email, html, mailx

I'd like to send a html file from a host using mailx but instead of interpreting it as html it would send it out as text (html codes). Is there a way to send it as html?

```
(cat <<EOCAT
Subject: TEST email
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline
EOCAT
header
cat $MSGFILE
footer
) | mailx -r localhost@host.com myemail@website.com
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make it a multipart/mixed message, boundaries and all.

```
( cat <<EOCAT
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: $from
To: $to
Cc: $cc
Subject: TEST email w/ HTML
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=NextPart_0123456789
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
--NextPart_0123456789
Content-Type: text/html
EOCAT
cat header.html
cat html_message_body.html
cat footer.html ) | mailx -r localhost@host.com myemail@website.com
```

Comment: (and make sure that the file you contain really is 7bit encoded! - or use cat -v)

Comment: tried. doesnt work on me. :(

Comment: What OS are you using?  If mailx isn't working, you could try piping to `sendmail -t` instead.

Comment: `mailx` didn't work for me on OSX, but `sendmail` did. Thank you!